# Backbone.js and DOM manipulation

Tags: javascript, jquery, mvvm, backbone.js, javascript-framework

I am very new to Javascript MVC frameworks and have a question related to Backbone.js
It is said that Backbone.js is very helpful when there are a lot of DOM manipulation.
Could you please give a practical example for the same. Like how using backbone.js would help make the code cleaner by having the DOM manipulation/HTML for presentation separate? 
How can it be used for common functionalities ?
Also any other practical examples of how Backbone.js is useful would be really helpful.

I have already gone through the tutorials on http://documentcloud.github.com/backbone/ But could not find some basic examples..

Thank you.

Answer (score -7, accepted):

Welcome to the wonderful world of MVVM! If you're new to it, I'd recommend starting out with Knockout JS - they have some good tutorials over at http://learn.knockoutjs.com/ that outline the advantages of the approach. I found Knockout a lot easier to work with than Backbone.

Comment: The question is clearly about backbone, not about choosing a Mv* framework.

Comment: And my answer is clearly a polite way of saying there's a nicer alternative for beginners in this area.

Comment: Not saying you were impolite, just that this is irrelevant to the question. This should not be a place for proselytism, imagine if I go to a Ruby question and say "here, try node", or a Java question and say try C#... you get the idea.

Comment: @thedixon : Even though my question is about Backbone.js , the link which you have given for another similar framework (Knockout.js) seems to be extremely good..A +1 from me...I mean the tutorial is explained in a very simple manner...Though I'll still keep the question open for responses related to Backbone.js

Answer (score 0):

From the doc

> Backbone's only hard dependency is Underscore.js ( > 1.3.1). For RESTful persistence, history support via Backbone.Router and DOM manipulation with Backbone.View, include json2.js, and either jQuery ( > 1.4.2) or Zepto.

The view is just a convention and the underscore library creates your DOM elements, although you could add some logic in there. Once your DOM is created you could manipulate it, using jQuery.